# How to validate an Azure B2C JWT token in a web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

Literally as per the title, I can get a token from Azure B2C via my web client, now all I need to do is validate that in my API.

This is my `appsettings.json` (details changed but the numbered GUIDs shown match each other in the real file):

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://login.mydomain.net/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Audience": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
    "Instance": "https://login.mydomain.net",
    "Domain": "mydomain.net",
    "ClientId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
    "TenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnection": "Data Source=MyAppDebug.db;Cache=Shared"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And I've tried these in my `Startup.cs`:

```
// Throws "System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
// there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found."
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

```
// Throws "System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration
// from: 'System.String'."
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C);
```

```
// Throws "System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration
// from: 'System.String'."
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Audience"];
                options.Authority = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Authority"];
            });
```

```
// Throws "System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration
// from: 'System.String'."
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(
                    (jwtOptions) =>
                    {
                        // I've commented this out because I don't yet have roles set up in
                        // Azure, but I have to include something for jwtOptions otherwise
                        // it won't build.
                        //// jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "groups";
                    },
                    (options) =>
                    {
                        options.ClientId = this.Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
                        options.TenantId = this.Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"];
                        options.Domain = this.Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Domain"];
                        options.Instance = this.Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"];
                    });
```

I'm at my wits end and can't understand how this is so difficult. Microsoft guides and documentation, as usual, are nothing short of useless.

I have a valid JWT token, all I want to do is validate it's signature, audience, issuer and claims. So far it's taken longer to try and validate this token than it did to set up the B2C directory, register for a Google dev account and obtain credentials to add to Azure, register my applications, add my own custom scope, create client secrets, implement into my web app and sign up new users.

Answer (score 3):

I eventually found out that I (or rather, the API) was not constructing the URL of the issuer properly, it needs to include the policy used to create the token (Sign Up/Sign In policy).

This is what I needed in the `appsettings.json` file:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.mydomain.net",
    "ClientId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "TenantId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpIn"
  }
```

And this is the code I used in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
    .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
        {
            jwtOptions.Authority =
                $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId"]}/v2.0/";
            jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
        });
```

That being said, the exception type and message I was getting is extremely unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/validating-an-adfs-jwt-a47099b014b9) a while back in the context of ADFS but the principles are the same.

B2C also has a [well-known endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#validate-signature) that you can use to check the signature.

Also, for [.NET Core](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/01/15/creating-and-validating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core/).

And a ton of libraries [here](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: Thank you for this, I've finally found that I was constructing the issuer URL wrongly by not including the name of the policy that issued the token in the first place. I've posted the code I ended up using which is a little more succinct. The third link you provided will be very useful as I now need to build something that can create tokens on the fly for unit testing, as all of my tests from the old authentication method are now screwed!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the "SignUpSignInPolicyId" in the appsettings.json configurations. Please make sure to use the exact policy name if you are using a custom policy.

Comment: Yeah this is something else to note - Microsoft, in trying to make everything easier, have hidden away defaults that aren't immediately obvious e.g. if you use Microsoft.Identity.Web to add authentication to an application and give it an `IConfiguration` object with no other parameters, it presumes that the relevant config section is named "AzureAd". It is an optional parameter which can be changed, but it isn't immediately obvious if you're just starting out with this kind of thing. Same thing with the name of the policy.